context value is not being updated on time
context.tsx
import { PropsWithChildren, createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import auth_svc from "../services/authServices";
import { Result, message } from "antd";

interface Result {
  _id: String | null;
  fullname: String | null;
  accessToken: String | null;
}
type usertypes = Result | null;

type AuthContextType = {
  verifyToken: () => Promise<void>;
  user: usertypes;
  logoutUser: () => void;
};

type AuthProviderProps = PropsWithChildren<{}>;

const defaultAuthContext: AuthContextType = {
  verifyToken: async () => {},
  user: null,
  logoutUser: () => null,
};

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(defaultAuthContext);

export const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within AuthProvider");
  }
  return context;
};

export default function AuthProvider({ children }: AuthProviderProps) {
  const [user, setuser] = useState<usertypes | null>(null);
  async function verifyToken(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
      if (token && !user) {
        let res = await auth_svc.getLoggedInUser();
        setuser(res);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }

  const logoutUser = (): void => {
    try {
      localStorage.clear();
      setuser(null);
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ verifyToken, user, logoutUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

private routes
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "./context/context";
import auth_svc from "./services/authServices";
import { Spin } from "antd";

const PrivateRoutes = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const { user, verifyToken } = useAuth();
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const validateToken = async () => {
      await verifyToken();
      if (!user) {
        navigate("/signin", { replace: true })
      } else {
        setLoader(false)
      }
    }
   validateToken();
  }, [user]);

  return loader ?  <Spin fullscreen={true} /> : children;
};

export default PrivateRoutes;

login
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const onFinish: FormProps<FieldType>["onFinish"] = async (values) => {
    setLoading(true);
    let response = await auth_svc.login(values);
    if (response) {
      setLoading(false);
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    }
  };

routing
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/signin",
    element: <Login key="adminlogin" />,
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <PrivateRoutes>
        <App key="app" />
      </PrivateRoutes>
    ),
  },
 
]);

const Routing = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </Provider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

AuthServices
import HttpServices from "./httpService";

class AuthServices extends HttpServices {
  login = async (data: {}) => {
    try {
      let res = await this.postRequest("signin", data, {});
      if (res) {
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", res.data.result.accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem("user", res.data.result.fullname);
        return true;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };

  getLoggedInUser = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await this.getRequest("/signin", {
        login: true,
      });
      if (response) return response.data.result;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
}

const auth_svc = new AuthServices();
export default auth_svc;

When I click on logged in the auth_Svc.login function retrieves the value and saves the token and name in localStorage. After response is true in login function it redirects to "/", home, which is protected by PrivateRoute. In private route it checks if there is user in context. The context is updates by the function verifyToken which gets the token from localStorage and verifies it, and after success it stores it to context. But the problem here is it does not render the children component by PrivateRoute at the first time click the login button but on second time am signed in. What is the cause? I have checked everything the context value is not being retrieved in PrivateRoute at first, but on second time it is.

Issue
The issue is that logging doesn't update the user state in the AuthContext. Sure, localStorage is updated, but that alone isn't enough to trigger React to do anything. It's not until you reload the page and the verifyToken function is called in a useEffect hook to read the localStorage and update the user state.
Solution Suggestion
I suggest creating a login handler in AuthContext that calls the auth_svc.login function and updates the user state prior to the Login component's handler then navigating to the "/" path.
Example:
AuthProvider
Create a login handler that calls and awaits the auth_svc.login method and passes the authentication payload through, and upon successful authentication and fetching the current user update the user state.
export default function AuthProvider({ children }: AuthProviderProps) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<usertypes | null>(null);

  async function verifyToken(): Promise<void> {
    ....
  }

  const loginUser = async (data: {}) => {
    try {
      const user = await auth_svc.login(data);
      setUser(user);
    } catch (err) {
      // catch and handle/ignore
      throw err; // rethrow for callees
    }
  };

  const logoutUser = (): void => {
    ....
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ verifyToken, user, loginUser, logoutUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

AuthServices
Update the login handler to call the getLoggedInUser method upon successful login to get and return the current user object to callees.
class AuthServices extends HttpServices {
  login = async (data: {}) => {
    try {
      const res = await this.postRequest("signin", data, {});
      if (res) {
        localStorage.setItem("accessToken", res.data.result.accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem("user", res.data.result.fullname);
      }
      return this.getLoggedInUser(); // <-- return "user"
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };

  getLoggedInUser = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await this.getRequest("/signin", {
        login: true,
      });
      return response.data.result;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
}

Login
Login can simply call and await the loginUser callback accessed from the AuthContext. If no error is thrown or there are no Promise rejections, then the login and fetching of the current user should have been successful and the handler can redirect to "/".
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { loginUser } = useAuth();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const onFinish: FormProps<FieldType>["onFinish"] = async (values) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await loginUser(values);
      // No thrown error so login succeeded
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    } catch (err) {
      // catch and handle/ignore
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  ...
};

PrivateRoutes
Update the PrivateRoutes component to just call verifyToken when the component mounts, conditionally render the loading indicator, and once loading is complete, conditionally render the children or the redirect to sign in.
const PrivateRoutes = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const { user, verifyToken } = useAuth();
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const validateToken = async () => {
      try {
        await verifyToken();
      } catch (err) {
        // catch and handle/ignore
      } finally {
        setLoader(false);
      }
    }
   validateToken();
  }, []);

  if (loader) {
    return <Spin fullscreen />;
  }

  return user ? children : <Navigate to="/signin" replace />;
};


everything is working fine but when i refresh the page am back to login page .
i have privateRoute which check for user and even call the setProvider function inside useEffect the main function of that function is to set user  in context which ultimately will be true and should render the children but no i  redirects me to login page. why is that ?

@alex The validateToken callback has a closure over the initially null user state value so when the verifyToken function returns a resolved Promise it's accessing the stale user value, not what the current state value actually is. I've updated with further suggestion for the PrivateRoutes component.
